# Finding unique combinations and their numbers using SQL

Tags: sql

Stuck trying to write the SQL to find a list of unique combinations and their respective numbers such as given a table (mytable), column 1 (col1) and column 2 (col2)

mytable:

```
Col1  Col2
A      A1
B      A1
A      A1
B      B1
A      A2
B      B1
```

sql results

```
Col1  Col2  Number
A     A1     2
A     A2     1
B     A1     1
B     B1     2
```

I can get one part or the other but not both.

Comment: please provide what you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats wrong with this?

```
Select col1, col2, count(*) from yourtable group by col1, col2
```

Comment: Either way appears to work. Adding the COUNT(*) syntax is different.  Going to have to think about why that works compared to the direction I was going. Either way works… thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col2, count(*)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Comment: that distinct is redundant